# Prove: $\log_{2}{3} < \log_{3}{6}$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

How should I prove that $\log_{2}{3} < \log_{3}{6}$?

I tried something like this: $2^{\log_{2}{3}}< 2^{\log_{3}{6}}$, $3<6^{\log_{3}{2}}$,  $\log_{6}{3}<\log_{6}{6^{\log_{3}{2}}}=\log_{3}{2}$, $\frac{1}{\log_{3}{6}}< \log_{3}{2}$. $\frac{1}{1+\log_{3}{2}}<\log_{3}{2}$, but still nothing.

Comment: Interestingly, the function $$\log_x(x+1)-1-\log_{x+1}x$$ is positive on $(1,x_*)$ and negative on $(x_*,\infty)$, where $$x_*\approx 1.95252$$ Hence, indeed the result asked (which is the case $x=2$) holds but proofs that it holds should be able to discriminate between the cases $x=2$ and, say, $x=1.95$... Which is definitely not encouraging.

Comment: Likewise, $$\log_2x=\log_x(2x)$$ has a root at $$x^*\approx3.0696$$ which is suspiciously close to the value of interest $x=3$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\log_23$ vs $\log_36$

> Multiply each term by $5$:

$5\log_23$ vs $5\log_36$

> Apply logarithm rules:

$\log_23^5$ vs $\log_36^5$

> Simplify:

$\log_2243$ vs $\log_37776$

> Conclude:

$\log_2243<\log_2256=8=\log_36561<\log_37776$

---

Hence $\log_23<\log_36$

Comment: Brilliant, you just calculated $log_2 3$ and $log_3 6$ and see which one is bigger :D

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov: Well, not quite. But in order to conclude the direction of the inequality, I applied an identical sequence of "direction-preserving" operations on each term ("preserving" - in opposed to multiplying by a negative number, for example). Anyhow... Thank you :)

Comment: But still better then other answers

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov: Thanks :)

Comment: I guess it's the only way. I was trying with some inequalities (arithmetic, geometric...) but in the end it would be also an approximation

Answer (score 6):

From what you did, we want to prove that 
$$\frac{1}{1+\log_32}\lt \log_32,$$
i.e.
$$\log_32\gt \frac{\sqrt 5-1}{2},$$
i.e.
$$2\gt 3^{(\sqrt 5-1)/2},$$
i.e.
$$2^2\gt 3^{\sqrt 5-1},$$
i.e.
$$3\cdot 2^2\gt 3^{\sqrt 5}$$
It is sufficient to prove that
$$12\gt 3^{2.25},$$
i.e.
$$12^2\gt 3^4\sqrt 3,$$
i.e.
$$16\gt 9\sqrt 3$$
i.e.
$$16^2\gt 81\cdot 3$$
which holds.

Answer (score 5):

Here is mine...

$$\log_2 3=\frac{\log_2 243}5<\frac{\log_2 256}5=8/5$$
$$\log_3 2=\frac{\log_3 32}5>\frac{\log_3 27}5=3/5$$
$$\log_3 6=\log_3 2+\log_3 3>1+3/5=8/5>\log_2 3$$

Answer (score 2):

Use:

1. $$\log_2(3)=\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(2)}$$
2. $$\log_3(6)=\frac{\ln(6)}{\ln(3)}=\frac{\ln(2\cdot3)}{\ln(3)}=\frac{\ln(2)+\ln(3)}{\ln(3)}=1+\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(3)}=1+\frac{1}{\log_2(3)}$$

So, you need to prove that:

$$\log_2(3)<\log_3(6)\space\space\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\space\log_2(3)<1+\frac{1}{\log_2(3)}$$

Comment: Right, but why $$\log_2(3)<1+\frac{1}{\log_2(3)}\ ?$$

Comment: I did not state that, that is what the OP has to prove.

Comment: Then you are not answering the question since the OP asks "How should I prove that..."

Comment: OK, and how should I prove your last inequality? I asked you because now, I'm trying to prove that: $\frac{1}{1+\log_{3}{2}}<\log_{3}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

You can use the fact that

$$\log_a(b)=\frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(a)}$$

so you can rewrite your inequation

$$\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(2)}<\frac{\ln(6)}{\ln(3)}$$

if and only if

$$\ln^2(3)<\ln(2\times 3)\ln 2=\ln(2)(\ln(2)+\ln(3)).$$

Comment: See the comments on the other answer, which fully apply to the present one. (In the present case, additionally, the mention "Hint" can be viewed as misleading.)

Comment: Why is it true?

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the same answer as barak manos's and Djura Marinkov's, mostly just presented in a different fashion, as one long string of self-explanatory equalities and inequalities:

$$\begin{align}
5\log_23&=\log_2243\\
&\lt\log_2256\\
&=8\\
&=5+\log_327\\
&\lt5+\log_332\\
&=5\log_33+5\log_32\\
&=5\log_36
\end{align}$$